# I’m going to Russia. Where should I exchange my currency?

Tags: currency, foreign-exchange, eur-euro, russia, rub-ruble

Is it better to go abroad with euros? What is the best kind of place to exchange currency?

Comment: There's a travel stack, why don't you ask there? (and I believe its been asked there, in fact)

Comment: @littleadv Russian currency hasn't been discussed at the travel SE (yet), though Euros have been.  Still, *Travel* might yield the better answer, even though this is on-topic subject matter here too.

Comment: Related questions at *Travel* include: [When traveling to a country with a different currency, how should you take your money?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10), [Should I change most of my money in my home country or in the destination country?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1911)  Also, I suggest you mention in your question where you are coming from and/or what your home currency is.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid exchanging in airports, hotels and other typical tourist locations as you get much worse  rates (this is true not only in Russia).

Only banks can run currency exchange operations in Russia. Find any regular bank outlet and exchange there. Euros are as common as USD, thus there won't be any problems. Be prepared that no one will speak English or any other foreign language in a bank (even if it's an international brand).

Comment: I had actually experienced the best USD-GBP exchange rate at the Heathrow airport....